# Laravel 7.x call Controller method in Listener with construct variables

Tags: laravel, events, controller, construct

I want to create an invite when a member request is approved, using Events and Listeners in Laravel 7.

Invite controller:

```
class InviteController extends Controller
{

    private InviteRepositoryInterface $invite_repository;

    public function __construct(InviteRepositoryInterface $invite_repository)
    {
        $this->invite_repository = $invite_repository;
    }

    public function __invoke(InviteRequest $request)
    {
        $member_request = MemberRequest::find($request->member_request_id);
        if ($this->_MemberRequestIsValid($member_request))
            return response()->json(['error' => ['message' => 'Please, enter an existing member request.', 'object' => $member_request]]);

        $this->invite_repository->createByMemberRequestId($member_request->id);

        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
```

What I tried: `redirect()->route('invite', ['member_request_id' => $event->member_request->id]);`
and: `app(InviteController::class)->__invoke(['member_request_id' => $event->member_request->id]);`

Both didn't work because of constructor.

UPDATE:
Listener:

```
namespace App\Listeners\MemberRequest\Approved;

use App\Events\MemberRequest\Approved;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Registration\Invite\InviteController;

class CreateInvite
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param Approved $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Approved $event)
    {
        redirect()->route('invite', ['member_request_id' => $event->member_request->id]);
        // app(InviteController::class)->__invoke(['member_request_id' => $event->member_request->id]);
    }
}
```

When I fire the event, the invite is not created but the InviteController invoke method does work according to my tests.

Testresults:
[image: Testresults]

Comment: what's not working?

Comment: include the listener

Comment: I updated it with the listener and the testresults.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using repositories.

```
(new InviteRepository(new MemberRequestRepository()))->createByMemberRequestId($event->member_request->id);
```